# Does gzip accept stdin?

Tags: command-line, bash, gzip, xargs

When i  pipe to `gzip` it can not accept stdin i should using `xargs`to convert stdin to argument

```
$ls
1.txt
$ls |xargs gzip && ls 
1.txt.gz
```

every thing is ok . but when i want to compress a cpio archive file

```
$ls | cpio -ov | gzip > archive.cpio.gz
```

also it is ok and this `ls | cpio -ov | xargs gzip`  does not work.why in the second situation `gzip` accept stdin and it can not accept argument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a difference between *command-line arguments* and *standard input*.

`gzip` accepts *filenames* as arguments. It will read the raw data from the specified files and compress them. If you have a command outputting a list of filenames, you can use `xargs` to pass those filenames to `gzip` as command-line arguments.

However, if no file arguments are passed to `gzip`, it defaults to read its *raw data* from *standard input* and print the compressed result to standard output. If you have a command outputting raw data which you want to compress, you can pipe it to `gzip`.

Comment: thank you,i read many question about xargs i could not understand it .your mean is xargs only convert  a list of file names to arguments. it is not completely true to saying xargs convert stdin to argument?

Comment: `xargs` reads text from its standard input (usually you use a pipe to get another command's output there) and constructs a new command line composed of its own arguments and the text from standard input and executes that new command. It does not care whether the input are file names or anything else, just in your example it makes only sense with file names.

Comment: sorry i am a newbie in linux,when i pipe `cmd1 | cmd2 ` cmd 2 see a text from its stdin and it can not recognizable for those command that accept file names as argument....in my example entire data (not only file name) write to stdout and it is possible for pipe to gzip without xargs, are these correct?

Comment: my means is if the output of cmd1 is a list of filenames

Comment: I'm sorry, you are confusing me.